# Debian Squeeze doesn't have sound

Tags: audio, debian-squeeze

Newly installed Debian squeeze doesn't have sound. I have pulseaudio installed and other thing. But not able to get the sound.

My Bad..I should have provide this info before..

bhaskar@bhaskar-laptop:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Here is alsamixer setting:
[image: alsamixser setting]

bhaskar@bhaskar-laptop:~$ sudo /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
Password:
snd_seq_dummy           1119  0
snd_seq_oss            25900  0
snd_seq_midi_event      4696  1 snd_seq_oss
snd_seq                42680  5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_pcm_oss            34554  0
snd_mixer_oss          14726  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_via82xx            17595  0
snd_maestro3           14031  0
snd_es1968             19684  0
snd_ens1371            15821  0
snd_ac97_codec         90095  4 snd_via82xx,snd_maestro3,snd_es1968,snd_ens1371
ac97_bus                 834  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_ens1370            16290  0
gameport                6861  4 snd_via82xx,snd_es1968,snd_ens1371,snd_ens1370
snd_cs4236             22435  0
snd_wss_lib            18374  1 snd_cs4236
snd_sb16                7613  0
snd_opl3_lib            7370  2 snd_cs4236,snd_sb16
snd_sb16_dsp            7732  1 snd_sb16
snd_sb16_csp            8489  1 snd_sb16
snd_sb_common          10338  3 snd_sb16,snd_sb16_dsp,snd_sb16_csp
snd_mpu401_uart         5095  4 snd_via82xx,snd_es1968,snd_cs4236,snd_sb16
snd_rawmidi            15638  3 snd_ens1371,snd_ens1370,snd_mpu401_uart
snd_seq_device          4505  5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq,snd_opl3_lib,snd_rawmidi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     20152  1
snd_hda_codec_idt      47981  1
snd_hda_intel          18443  5
snd_hda_codec          61720  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep               4772  3 snd_opl3_lib,snd_sb16_csp,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                59843  15 snd_pcm_oss,snd_via82xx,snd_maestro3,snd_es1968,snd_ens1371,snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1370,snd_cs4236,snd_wss_lib,snd_sb16,snd_sb16_dsp,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_timer              15717  5 snd_seq,snd_wss_lib,snd_opl3_lib,snd_pcm
snd                    43891  35 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_via82xx,snd_maestro3,snd_es1968,snd_ens1371,snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1370,snd_cs4236,snd_wss_lib,snd_sb16,snd_opl3_lib,snd_sb16_dsp,snd_sb16_csp,snd_sb_common,snd_mpu401_uart,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_timer
soundcore               4641  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          5925  6 snd_via82xx,snd_es1968,snd_ens1370,snd_wss_lib,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm

Hope this will help.How to change from Digital to Analog in Kmix?? that will be key...or in alsamixer..

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your post - [faq#signatures]

Comment: what is that??I am not sure what you are talking about...I believe I haven't done anything on that part when posting this question...clear me..

Comment: please don't add "TIA unixbhaskar". http://superuser.com/posts/327334/revisions

Answer (score 1):

Well, having some idea of your exact hardware setup would help - debian often has a limited subset of drivers, but i'd start with installing and using lshw (debian suggests using hotplug for usb, and lspci for pci, but lshw tends to work for me, mostly) to identify the sound card, and following debian's documentation for setting up [alsa](http://wiki.debian.org/ALSA#Troubleshooting)

The bit about realtek sound cards looks especially interesting, since most cheap and cheerful built in soundcards are realtek, and you apparently need to download and install those drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Squeeze it harder! Ok, seriously, you could just be missing the right driver. There is not much info here to go on. What does `lspci` show you? Or `lsusb`? What kind of platform is it?

BTW, chuck the pulseaudio, it won't help you. Install alsa-libs and alsa-tools.